# mouseenter/mouseleave in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have a script that when you hover (mouseenter/mouseleave) it uses jQuery's easing plugin to make the link easeOutBounce. I also have css styling on the jQuery as my images are created using a css sprite so depending on the hover state the X and Y positons change. This works fine in browsers apart from Firefox.

I was wondering if anyone has come across this problem before and a solution they may have found to solve this? I have identified from research that it is something to do with the mouseenter/mouseleave method.

Here is an example of how the code works for a link:

(example shows re-named classes and div's)

```
$(function() {
    $('#navigation').on('mouseenter', '#link-1:not(.selected)', function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundPositionX:0,
            backgroundPositionY:0
        }, 1000, 'easeOutBounce');
    }).on('mouseleave', '#link-1:not(.selected)', function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundPositionX:0,
            backgroundPositionY:-156
        }, 700, 'easeOutBack');
   });
});
```

This is repeated for other links on the page.

/* Edited as FF suggestion- does not like the background element but works slightly when edited like this but the hover state for background pos needs to be 00 and doesn't like the -84 and the hover takes the sprite to the side rather than down!

```
$(function() {
    $('#navigation #link-1:not(.selected)').hover(
function () {
       $(this).stop().animate({
          'background-position':0
        }, 1000, 'easeOutBounce');
},
function () {
      $(this).stop().animate({
            'background-position': 0 -156
        }, 700, 'easeOutBack');
    }
    );
});
```

Comment: <<This works fine in browsers apart from Firefox.>>  So, what happen in FF?

Comment: Create a JSFIddle that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I will sort a fiddle out now. In FF it just doesn't so any animation or anything, links still work though.

Comment: I cant sort out a link at the moment using the present code as it uses codeigniter/php so i will mock an example up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the problem.
If the problem is that mouseleave does not trigger, I resolved it by using the hover() function instead of mouseenter/mouseleave.

Can you try this code ?

```
$(function() {
    $('#navigation #link-1:not(.selected)').hover(
function () {
       $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundPositionX:0,
            backgroundPositionY:0
        }, 1000, 'easeOutBounce');
},
function () {
      $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundPositionX:0,
            backgroundPositionY:-156
        }, 700, 'easeOutBack');
}
);
});
```

If the problem is that the animation is sometimes "jumpy", change the stop function to stop(true, true)

Comment: Hi there, had a look at your code and still no luck in FF, very strange!

Comment: Replace backgroundPositionX & Y by 'background-position': 0 0 and 'background-position': 0 -156px

Comment: Had a go of changing the background position and i get movement in FF but a have syntax errors in the script ( it doesn't like the 00 and px) and when it moves it moves to the side and breaks, i think it's nearly there! I will add in a copy of what i have used in the example explained above.

Comment: If you still have problem put the values in a string : '0 0' and '0 -156px'. Hope it helps